Как восстановить дерево Хаффмана
Есть готовый алгоритм Хаффмана на C++. В моём случае я храню символы и их частоты в файле, по ним нужно восстановить дерево. Возможно ли это или нужно иначе сохранять дерево?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>


using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int a; 
    wchar_t c; 
    Node* left, * right; 
    Node()
    {
        left = right = NULL;
    }
    Node(Node* L, Node* R) 
    {
        left = L;
        right = R;
        a = L->a + R->a;
    }
};
struct MyCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Node* l, const Node* r) const { return l->a < r->a; }
};
vector<bool> code;
map<char, vector<bool> > table;
void BuildTable(Node* root)
{
    if (root->left != NULL) 
    {
        code.push_back(0); 
        BuildTable(root->left); 
    }
    if (root->right != NULL) 
    {
        code.push_back(1);
        BuildTable(root->right);
    }
    if (root->c)
        table[root->c] = code;

    if (code.size() != 0)
    {
        code.pop_back(); 
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int check;
    cout << "Желаете закодировать Ваш файл?\n 1 - Да.\n 2 - Нет." << endl;
    cin >> check;

    if (check == 1)
    {
        wifstream f("C:\\Users\\artem\\Downloads\\test.txt");
        f.imbue(std::locale(".utf-8"));
        map<wchar_t, int> m; 
        while (!f.eof())
        {
            wchar_t c = f.get();
            m[c]++;
        }

        std::wofstream file_with_table("file_with_table.txt");
        file_with_table.imbue(std::locale(".utf-8"));

        map<wchar_t, int>::iterator i;
        for (i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
        {
            wchar_t sym = i->first;
            file_with_table << sym << " " << i->second << endl;
        }

        file_with_table.close();

        list<Node*> t; 
        for (map<wchar_t, int>::iterator itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr) 
        {
            Node* p = new Node; 
            p->c = itr->first;
            p->a = itr->second;
            t.push_back(p); 
        }
 
        while (t.size() != 1) 
        {
            t.sort(MyCompare()); 
            Node* SonL = t.front(); 
            t.pop_front(); 
            Node* SonR = t.front();
            t.pop_front();
            Node* parent = new Node(SonL, SonR); 
            t.push_back(parent);
        }
        Node* root = t.front();   
        BuildTable(root);
        f.clear(); f.seekg(0);
        ofstream g("output.bin");
        int count = 0;
        char buf = 0;
        int show_coded_text;
        int start_time;
        cout << "\nЖелаете увидеть закодированный текст?\n 1 - Да.\n 2 - Нет.\n ";
        cin >> show_coded_text;
        start_time = clock();
        int n;

        while (!f.eof())
        {
            char c = f.get();
            vector<bool> x = table[c];
            for (n = 0; n < x.size(); n++)
            {
                buf = buf | x[n] << (7 - count); 
                count++;
                if (count == 8) 
                {
                    count = 0;
                    g << buf;
                    buf = 0;
                }
                if (show_coded_text == 1)
                {
                    cout << x[n];
                }
            }
        }
        f.close();
        g.close();
        int end_time = clock();
        int search_time = end_time - start_time;
        cout << "\n\nЗатраченное время: " << search_time / 1000.0 << "\n";
        int number;
        cout << endl << endl << "    Желаете декодировать Ваш файл?\n 1 - Да.\n 2 - Нет." << endl;
        cin >> number;
        int start_decoding_time;
        cout << endl;
        if (number == 1)
        {
            ifstream F("output.bin");
            wofstream D("Decoded text.txt");
            D.imbue(std::locale(".utf-8"));



            Node* p = root;
            count = 0;
            char byte;
            byte = F.get();
            int show_decoded_text;
            cout << "    Желаете увидеть декодированный файл?\n 1 - Да.\n 2 - Нет.\n";
            cin >> show_decoded_text;
            start_decoding_time = clock();
            while (!F.eof())
            {
                bool b = byte & (1 << (7 - count));
                if (b)
                    p = p->right;
                else p = p->left;
                if ((p->left == NULL) && (p->right == NULL))
                {
                    if (show_decoded_text == 1)
                    {
                        cout << p->c;
                    }
                    D << p->c;
                    p = root;
                }
                count++;
                if (count == 8)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    byte = F.get();
                }
            }
            F.close();
            int stop_decoding_time = clock();
            int search_decoding_time = stop_decoding_time - start_decoding_time;
            cout << "\nФайл декодирован.";
            cout << "\nЗатраченное время: " << search_decoding_time / 1000.0 << "\n";
        }
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
}




Что значит восстановить? Алгоритм Хаффмана как раз и строит дерево по символы и их частоты (пример)

@MBo, после архивации у меня есть таблица частот символов. Мне же для разархивации нужно по ней построить дерево, которое было во время архивации или я не прав?

Нет, после архивации есть последовательность битов типа 1011010110111101, которая составлена из кодов узлов дерева Хаффмана. Для разархивации нужна таблица кодов или дерево, из последовательности его не создать

Получается, после архивации нужно хранить символ и его код, вместо частоты? Насколько это экономно?

Код короче частоты. Однако навскидку описание практической реализации хранения дерева или таблицы оказалось не так просто найти, статьи часто ограничиваются построением кодов и вскользь про хранение. "компактное представление такой дополнительной информации - это отдельная интересная задача, в которую я не буду сейчас углубляться"

Обычно, во "взрослых" архиваторах хранят длину кода для каждого символа, а не частоты, дерево и т.д.
